# Directed graph - Unreachable node

Tags: algorithm, graph

What is the best way to find unreachable nodes in a directed weighted graph. I already use A* for pathfinding. So, the data contains list of nodes, links, and adjacency list. I was thinking BFS/DFS (which is right one??), and look for unmarked nodes. Number of nodes may be 100 - 200, so it is not a big graph. Is there a better way?

Comment: BFS will be your best bet...i dnt think there is a better way than that....

Comment: hmm a lot of graph questions lately.  Hope you aren't in my class this semester.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either BFS or DFS would do fine: you need to traverse the entire subgraph from your starting vertex before potentially declaring some of its nodes unreachable, so it does not matter in what order you discover the nodes that you can reach. Since it is not a big graph, the recursive DFS should not present a problem, because even if the graph is actually a list, 200 nodes should not be nearly enough to threaten a stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Unreachable *from where*? You have to give a start node. A BFS which fills in a `bool[]` with one entry for each graph node will work, where the node visit operation sets the `bool[i]` to true for node `i`. At the end, the nodes `i` with `bool[i]==false` are the ones that are not reachable. This should be optimal in terms of runtime. Start with the "start node" in your BFS frontier/queue.